# iPad 2 wifi only FaceTime with iPhone 4s

Tags: ipad, iphone

I recently got an iPad 2 wifi only and my boyfriend just got the new iPhone 4s but if I try and FaceTime him it just rings out. I know that he only has 3G at home, is this why? And how can he FaceTime me when I have no number on my iPad? Really confused please help!

Answer (score 3):

Facetime only works over WiFi and can find people using either an e-mail address or phone number.

Comment: That's it exactly.

Answer (score -1):

I think FaceTime work only on WiFi between iOS/OS X devices. It is totally free which why the Mobile GSM operator don't want you to use it over 3G.